# Whats the difference between if( null == this.somevariable ) and if( this.somevariable == null)

Tags: c#, if-statement

Dumb question I get it..but what the difference between these two statements

```
if( null == this.someVariable)
{
 //do something
}

and 

if( this.someVariable == null )
{
//do something.
}
```

Comment: No difference. First one is C/C++ [Yoda comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) style

Comment: No difference between these two statements is there

Comment: @Ballbin That statement is already an error in C#

Answer (score 5):

They are the same from a code point of view. Some people prefer the first style, because if you then make a mistake and type `=` instead of `==` you'll get an error

Comment: no  there is no such  thing  in  c# try  it yourself stop  upvoting

Comment: @K.B: Yes, you are right. It's a habit from C++ programmers using C# ;)

Comment: @K.B agree, with C# you just can't use assignment by mistake. Well, except if you trying to compare with true/false, which I think is odd

Answer (score 4):

There's **absolutely** no difference at all. Except maybe which looks better to you.

It's a relic from the C\C++ world where:

```
if(null = someVariable)
{
}
```

Would give an error. But:

```
if(someVariable = null)
{
}
```

Would not.

Comment: Technically correct, but missing the reason why `null == x` is used. If you miss one of the `=`, it becomes an error.

Comment: @ssube that's not the reason. It's a relic from the C world.

Comment: This really is a good answer.  I was reviewing some sample MS code for Kinect libraries and was very puzzled as to why the first flavor was being used.  I swear had never seen that till today

Answer (score 1):

The 2 if's result in the same result for your example.

A more relevant example is something like:

```
   string text = null;

   if(text.Equals("something"))
   {
   }
```

Here, you will get a `NullReferenceException`, so another way of avoiding this is to reverse the comparison:

```
   string text = null;

   if("something".Equals(text))
   {
   }
```

This way, you know the constant `"something"` will always be valid and any comparable item will work, as the source object is valid.

Comment: this is why you shouldn't use the instance `Equals` method in general.  Use the static `object.Equals` method instead (or use the equality operator, as the question asks about), and the problem becomes moot.